# Observer pattern with actor

Tags: swift, concurrency, actor, swift-concurrency

I try to implement some repository that can notify about change its state.

```
protocol Observer {
}

actor Repository: Actor {
    var observers: [Observer] = []
    func add(observer: Observer) {
        self.observers.append(observer)
    }
}
```

and add unit test for it

```
func test_get_update() async {
    let repository = Repository()
    let observer = MockObserver()    
    await repository.add(observer: observer)
}
```

and get warning

> Non-sendable type 'any Observer' passed in implicitly asynchronous call to actor-isolated instance method 'add(observer:)' cannot cross actor boundary

but in main app there is no warning.

```
class Bar {
    func foo() async {
        let repository = Repository()
        let observer = MockObserver()
        
        await repository.add(observer: observer)
    }
}
```

I don't understand is this implementation of repository correct or not?

Comment: Is your main application being built with concurrency checking turned on Build Settings > Strict Concurrency Checking > Complete?

Comment: yes, is exactly the reason, why there is no warning in main app. I set checking only for test target

Comment: But anyway is it possible to implement Observer pattern with actor?

Comment: Yes, you can. You just need to make sure that your observers are `Sendable`. You might want to make this explicit in the protocol definition (e.g., `protocol Observer: Sendable {…}`).

Comment: If you haven’t seen it, WWDC 2022’s [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/) is a good introduction to “sendable” types. I find video’s incessant naïve visual metaphor a bit grating, but if you can get past that, it helps really understand “sendable” types.

Comment: yes, off course, if observer is sendable is piece of cake, but most of the time it will be some sort of view model that can not be sendable. For now I see solution - create helper class Observer: Sendable, ObserverProtocol { var completion: ()-> Void } and send it to repository. And ViewModel will interact with this helper class. But it looks like a trick and don't fully safe

Comment: At first I think that implement sendable for ViewModel will be problematic, but in my cases it already @MainActor isolated and from that reason sendable. Issue close :). Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly make your `Observer` a `Sendable` type:

```
protocol Observer: Sendable {
    func observe(something: Int)
}

struct MockObserver: Observer {
    func observe(something: Int) {
        print("I observed \(something)")
    }
}

actor Repository {
    private var observers: [any Observer] = []

    func add(observer: any Observer) {
        observers.append(observer)
    }

    private func notifyObservers(value: Int) {
        for observer in observers {
            observer.observe(something: value)
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        notifyObservers(value: 42)
    }
}


let myRepo = Repository()
Task {
    let myObserver = MockObserver()
    await myRepo.add(observer: myObserver)
    await myRepo.doSomething()
}
```

But since `Sendable` imposes so many restrictions on things, that might make implementing an interesting observer a challenge.

I would be inclined to use the `Observer` implementations already available in the Combine framework:

```
actor AnotherRepo {
    nonisolated let interestingState: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>;
    private let actualState = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>();

    init() {
        interestingState = actualState.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func doSomething() {
        actualState.send(42)
    }
}

let anotherRepo = AnotherRepo()
anotherRepo.interestingState.sink { print("I also observed \($0)") }

Task {
    await anotherRepo.doSomething()
}
```